# Calculate demand ID from previous record

Tags: sql, t-sql, calculated-columns

I am struggling to subtract date from previous record date based on record ID

I have a situation where I have to calculate the amount of time a record stayed in a particular status. It can only be derived from the previous record.

So basically it is supposed to be "If demand ID is same then calculate how long it stayed in a particular status before it was changed to a different one based on the column "created"

Please note this is log data and there can be multiple changes for one demand ID. Ideally, if I can calculate it in "days, hours, minutes, seconds" format

I am stuck on this for days and have not been able to get any workaround. Any help will be really appreciated

I am adding sample here as it is mentioned that sharing google drive is not a safe practice

Demand:ID   Demand Substatus    Created
1810        9/8/19 10:15
1810        10/3/19 11:14
1810        10/10/19 16:10
1810        10/24/19 16:53
1810        10/31/19 17:19
1810        11/10/19 10:26
1810        1/23/20 16:22
1810        4/3/20 15:06
1810        5/30/20 16:06
1810        9/17/20 15:45
1810        9/25/20 6:18
1810        10/8/20 18:15
1810        10/15/20 16:24
1810        10/22/20 14:53
1810        11/1/20 10:18
1810        11/5/20 13:34
1810        11/19/20 12:30
1810        11/26/20 16:51
1810        12/3/20 17:10
1810        12/10/20 16:06
1810        12/16/20 15:43
2077        8/5/19 8:39
2077        9/29/19 12:03
2077        10/7/19 8:10
2077        10/13/19 14:49
2077        11/26/20 15:43
2632        6/25/20 10:02
2632        8/12/20 14:58
2632        8/16/20 13:37
2632        4/1/21 23:49
1810    Approved by Financial Management    6/23/19 9:53
2077    Approved by Financial Management    7/25/19 8:48
1810    Approved by Manager 8/9/20 17:51
2632    Approved by Manager 1/16/20 18:01
1810    Assigned to Demand Manager  6/23/19 9:56
1810    Assigned to Demand Manager  8/20/20 22:40
2077    Contract Executed (Signed)  9/3/20 15:24
2632    Contract Executed (Signed)  3/25/21 11:25
2077    Demand Under Process    10/17/19 18:18
1810    Draft   5/27/19 14:08
1810    Draft   8/9/20 16:25
1810    Draft   8/9/20 17:30
2632    Draft   11/29/19 10:12
2632    Draft   11/29/19 10:14
2632    Draft   11/29/19 10:22
2632    Draft   11/29/19 10:23
2632    Draft   1/16/20 17:33
2077    LOI / LOA Issued    4/30/20 15:01
2077    LOI / LOA Issued    4/30/20 15:01
2077    LOI / LOA Issued    5/7/20 14:13
2077    LOI / LOA Issued    5/7/20 14:13
2632    LOI / LOA Issued    1/25/21 13:54
2632    On Hold 6/15/20 13:29
2632    On Hold 6/18/20 16:18
2632    On Hold 7/2/20 16:24
2632    On Hold 7/9/20 13:29
2632    On Hold 7/16/20 13:55
1810    Pending Director approval   8/9/20 17:51
2632    Pending Director approval   1/16/20 18:01
1810    Pending DM Review   6/23/19 9:53
1810    Pending DM Review   8/13/20 11:27
2077    Pending DM Review   7/25/19 8:48
2632    Pending DM Review   1/22/20 10:13
1810    Pending Manager Approval    5/27/19 14:08
1810    Pending Manager Approval    8/9/20 16:49
1810    Pending Manager Approval    8/9/20 17:32
2077    Pending Manager Approval    7/20/19 12:45
2632    Pending Manager Approval    11/29/19 10:25
2632    Pending Manager Approval    1/16/20 17:35
2077    Pending PR Creation / Update    7/25/19 8:49
2632    Pending PR Creation / Update    1/27/20 10:52
2632    Pending PR Creation / Update    7/27/20 10:24
2632    Pending Service Owner approval  1/20/20 14:33
2632    Pending Service Owner approval  1/20/20 14:34
1810    Pending User Input  6/23/19 11:18
1810    Pending User Input  8/6/19 15:28
1810    Pending User Input  8/28/19 15:21
2632    Pending User Input  1/26/20 10:51
2077    PO Issued   12/3/20 13:39
2632    PO Issued   4/6/21 9:54
2632    PR Pending Budget Approval (Finance Division)   1/29/20 10:31
2632    PR Pending Budget Approval (Finance Division)   1/29/20 10:31
2077    PR Pending Other Approvals  7/25/19 16:39
2632    Rejected by Manager 1/14/20 11:13
2077    SAP Contract Issued (Proc.) 11/19/20 16:45
2632    SAP Contract Issued (Proc.) 3/31/21 11:35
1810    Tender Issued   5/4/21 12:57
1810    Tender Issued   5/6/21 11:46
1810    Tender Issued   5/6/21 11:47
1810    Tender Issued   5/20/21 16:22
1810    Tender Issued   5/27/21 12:37
2077    Tender Issued   8/31/19 9:02
2077    Tender Issued   9/24/19 14:48
2077    Tender Issued   10/17/19 18:19
2077    Tender Issued   10/19/19 0:52
2632    Tender Issued   3/8/20 9:50
2632    Tender Issued   3/8/20 9:52
2632    Tender Issued   3/16/20 13:10
2632    Tender Issued   3/16/20 13:10
2632    Tender Issued   3/19/20 16:36
2632    Tender Issued   3/19/20 16:36
2632    Tender Issued   9/23/20 8:58
2632    Tender Issued   9/24/20 14:07
2632    Tender Issued   10/1/20 11:55
2632    Tender Issued   10/8/20 13:53
2632    Tender Issued   10/15/20 9:43
2632    Tender Issued   10/19/20 15:20
2632    Tender Issued   10/22/20 12:07
2632    Tender Issued   10/29/20 13:12
2632    Tender Issued   11/2/20 14:01
2632    Tender Issued   11/5/20 15:18
2632    Tender Issued   11/12/20 14:06
2632    Tender Issued   11/17/20 9:51
2632    Tender Issued   11/19/20 9:59
2632    Tender Issued   11/26/20 14:49
2632    Tender Issued   12/3/20 15:35
2632    Tender Issued   12/10/20 14:30
2632    Tender Issued   12/16/20 12:33
1810    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  7/8/21 12:14
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  1/2/20 12:16
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  1/2/20 12:17
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  1/30/20 15:39
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  1/30/20 15:40
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/6/20 15:23
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/6/20 15:24
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/13/20 13:29
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/13/20 13:29
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/20/20 15:41
2077    Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations  2/20/20 15:41
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/9/20 15:18
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/9/20 15:19
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/16/20 15:31
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/16/20 15:31
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    2/27/20 14:48
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    2/27/20 14:48
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/2/20 13:18
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/2/20 13:19
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/9/20 13:23
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/9/20 13:23
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/16/20 15:54
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/16/20 15:54
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/23/20 12:35
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    4/23/20 12:35
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/14/21 16:00
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Awarding    1/21/21 14:58
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 1/23/20 8:58
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 1/23/20 8:58
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/5/20 13:11
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/5/20 13:11
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/12/20 11:20
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/12/20 11:20
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/19/20 12:04
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/19/20 12:04
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/26/20 14:54
2077    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 3/26/20 14:54
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 12/21/20 14:25
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 12/24/20 16:32
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 12/31/20 13:10
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Commercials 1/7/21 14:04
1810    Under Committee Approvals - Tendering   3/25/21 17:30
1810    Under Committee Approvals - Tendering   4/1/21 10:33
1810    Under Committee Approvals - Tendering   4/9/21 0:20
1810    Under Committee Approvals - Tendering   4/17/21 18:12
2632    Under Committee Approvals - Tendering   9/17/20 15:44
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    5/14/20 12:17
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    5/21/20 13:59
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    5/21/20 14:00
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    5/30/20 3:43
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    5/30/20 3:43
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/4/20 16:27
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/4/20 16:28
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/11/20 13:15
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/11/20 13:15
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/18/20 12:20
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    6/25/20 13:22
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    7/2/20 14:13
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    7/9/20 13:43
2077    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    7/16/20 14:58
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    1/28/21 15:02
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    2/4/21 13:38
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    2/10/21 13:26
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    2/11/21 15:44
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    2/18/21 15:17
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    2/25/21 11:35
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    3/1/21 15:23
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    3/4/21 11:57
2632    Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)    3/11/21 13:38
1810    Under Contract Management Review (TNO)  8/16/20 14:50
2632    Under Contract Management Review (TNO)  1/22/20 11:02
2632    Under Contract Management Review (TNO)  1/26/20 10:13
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    7/23/20 12:39
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    7/29/20 17:00
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    8/6/20 12:53
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    8/13/20 15:12
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    8/20/20 15:35
2077    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    8/27/20 16:36
2632    Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)    3/18/21 14:29
1810    Under Financial Review  6/12/19 12:20
2077    Under Financial Review  7/20/19 13:03
2632    Under Financial Review  1/21/20 11:27
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   9/26/19 11:01
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   10/17/19 16:24
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   10/24/19 16:50
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/5/19 14:59
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/12/19 17:00
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/26/19 17:07
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/2/20 16:40
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/9/20 17:16
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/16/20 16:51
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/30/20 14:29
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/6/20 17:17
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/13/20 16:24
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/20/20 12:48
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/27/20 14:55
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/5/20 16:15
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/15/20 17:17
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/19/20 16:17
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/27/20 16:04
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/9/20 13:16
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/16/20 17:24
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/17/20 1:49
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/2/20 19:19
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/9/20 17:16
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/16/20 17:27
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/24/20 1:14
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/29/20 16:14
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   8/9/20 16:23
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   8/20/20 22:47
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   8/27/20 16:09
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   9/3/20 17:15
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   9/10/20 16:24
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   10/1/20 17:00
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   11/12/20 11:11
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/3/20 17:12
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/3/20 17:13
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/24/20 10:57
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   12/31/20 16:33
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/7/21 18:07
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/14/21 16:55
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/18/21 12:14
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/21/21 12:17
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   1/28/21 16:32
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/7/21 12:15
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/13/21 13:43
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/18/21 18:44
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   2/25/21 18:20
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/7/21 10:16
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/17/21 10:52
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   3/18/21 18:11
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/17/21 18:13
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/22/21 16:41
1810    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   4/29/21 15:40
2632    Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)   7/23/20 15:52
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/23/20 16:06
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/30/20 14:51
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/7/20 17:45
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/7/20 17:45
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/14/20 17:15
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/14/20 17:16
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/21/20 15:44
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/21/20 15:44
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/1/20 14:56
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/1/20 14:56
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/4/20 14:43
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/4/20 14:43
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/11/20 12:02
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/11/20 12:02
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/18/20 12:48
1810    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/25/20 11:58
2077    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   7/30/19 18:51
2077    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/7/19 12:21
2077    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/22/19 10:05
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/9/20 8:56
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/9/20 8:56
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/9/20 11:07
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/13/20 17:20
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/13/20 17:20
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/20/20 15:24
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/20/20 15:24
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/27/20 16:07
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   2/27/20 16:07
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   3/5/20 16:30
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   3/5/20 16:30
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   3/27/20 15:15
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   3/27/20 15:15
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/3/20 14:50
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/3/20 14:50
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/9/20 17:21
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/9/20 17:21
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/16/20 16:44
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/16/20 16:44
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/23/20 15:10
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/23/20 15:10
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/30/20 14:36
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   4/30/20 14:37
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/7/20 17:00
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/7/20 17:00
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/14/20 16:27
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/14/20 16:27
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/21/20 15:05
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/21/20 15:05
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/30/20 16:02
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   5/30/20 16:02
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/1/20 14:53
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/1/20 14:53
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/4/20 16:01
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/4/20 16:01
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/11/20 12:53
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   6/11/20 12:53
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   7/29/20 17:17
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/10/20 9:31
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/13/20 16:06
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/20/20 15:32
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   8/27/20 14:31
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   9/3/20 15:26
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   9/6/20 15:33
2632    Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)   9/10/20 10:59
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   9/10/20 10:41
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   9/17/20 13:29
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   9/24/20 13:04
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   10/1/20 15:56
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   10/8/20 15:24
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   10/15/20 15:06
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   10/22/20 16:05
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   10/29/20 15:24
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   11/5/20 15:22
2077    Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)   11/12/20 16:29
1810    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 6/3/21 17:07
1810    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 6/10/21 11:22
1810    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 6/20/21 0:32
1810    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 6/24/21 16:02
1810    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 7/1/21 13:05
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 10/20/19 9:38
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 10/24/19 15:15
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 10/31/19 15:32
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 10/31/19 15:32
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/7/19 17:42
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/7/19 17:42
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/16/19 0:45
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/16/19 0:45
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/16/19 0:53
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/16/19 0:53
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/21/19 15:58
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/21/19 15:58
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 11/28/19 14:58
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/5/19 15:13
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/5/19 15:13
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/11/19 8:35
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/11/19 8:36
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/23/19 15:02
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/23/19 15:02
2077    Under Technical Evaluation (TE) 12/26/19 15:28

The result should be something like

Duration(DD:HH:MM:SS)   DemandId    Created
0 Day(s) 0h 0m 59s  1000    11/12/2018 11:41
0 Day(s) 3h 4m 31s  1000    11/12/2018 11:42
0 Day(s) 0h 0m 32s  1001    11/12/2018 11:43
0 Day(s) 3h 2m 57s  1001    11/12/2018 11:43
0 Day(s) 0h 0m 1s   1002    11/14/2018 14:19
0 Day(s) 2h 37m 35s 1002    11/13/2018 10:22
0 Day(s) 3h 26m 1s  1002    11/13/2018 6:56
1 Day(s) 1h 19m 40s 1002    11/13/2018 13:00
10 Day(s) 21h 12m 30s   1002    11/29/2018 10:19
3 Day(s) 22h 59m 27s    1002    11/25/2018 11:20
4 Day(s) 21h 30m 36s    1002    11/20/2018 13:49
5 Day(s) 23h 29m 28s    1002    11/14/2018 14:20

Thanks

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output in the text-format here, not a link to some strange place

Comment: Please don't supply links to google drive files. Many of the users here are IT professionals and are *very* aware of how dangerous (and foolish) it is to download files from a stranger. You are no exception; we don't know who you are or what the download contains. If the information is important, include as content in the question, not an off-site link for a file download.

Comment: Better yet, can you post code to create a table and insert the values into that table, and make the data as small as you can while still serving as a workable sample to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the future you should provide a query with some sample data for everyone to work with. Normally I would have scrolled right past this because it was missing but, I was bored so I went ahead and copy/pasted the data from the spreadsheet into a query.

The answer to your question is to use `OVER PARTITION BY` to be able to see the previous or next record date so you can do your calculation. In your case the data needed a bit of cleaning up first. You have consecutive records for the same ID with the same status. I wrapped this all in cascading CTEs so you could see each step.

1. SampleData - the data
2. CleanupDates - dates were poorly formatted from the speadsheet so I added an extra step to convert them to datetime just to be safe.
3. CollapseSubStatus - `OVER PARTITION BY` to find consecutive records where the subStatus doesn't actually change and marks them as such.
4. Final select - Only looks at records where the subStatus actually changed, and then use `OVER PARTITION BY` to calculated the number of seconds that status existed before the next change happened

```
WITH
    SampleData AS (
    SELECT id,
           subStatus,
           createdDate
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (1810, '', '9/8/19 10:15'),
            (1810, '', '10/3/19 11:14'),
            (1810, '', '10/10/19 16:10'),
            (1810, '', '10/24/19 16:53'),
            (1810, '', '10/31/19 17:19'),
            (1810, '', '11/10/19 10:26'),
            (1810, '', '1/23/20 16:22'),
            (1810, '', '4/3/20 15:06'),
            (1810, '', '5/30/20 16:06'),
            (1810, '', '9/17/20 15:45'),
            (1810, '', '9/25/20 6:18'),
            (1810, '', '10/8/20 18:15'),
            (1810, '', '10/15/20 16:24'),
            (1810, '', '10/22/20 14:53'),
            (1810, '', '11/1/20 10:18'),
            (1810, '', '11/5/20 13:34'),
            (1810, '', '11/19/20 12:30'),
            (1810, '', '11/26/20 16:51'),
            (1810, '', '12/3/20 17:10'),
            (1810, '', '12/10/20 16:06'),
            (1810, '', '12/16/20 15:43'),
            (2077, '', '8/5/19 8:39'),
            (2077, '', '9/29/19 12:03'),
            (2077, '', '10/7/19 8:10'),
            (2077, '', '10/13/19 14:49'),
            (2077, '', '11/26/20 15:43'),
            (2632, '', '6/25/20 10:02'),
            (2632, '', '8/12/20 14:58'),
            (2632, '', '8/16/20 13:37'),
            (2632, '', '4/1/21 23:49'),
            (1810, 'Approved by Financial Management', '6/23/19 9:53'),
            (2077, 'Approved by Financial Management', '7/25/19 8:48'),
            (1810, 'Approved by Manager', '8/9/20 17:51'),
            (2632, 'Approved by Manager', '1/16/20 18:01'),
            (1810, 'Assigned to Demand Manager', '6/23/19 9:56'),
            (1810, 'Assigned to Demand Manager', '8/20/20 22:40'),
            (2077, 'Contract Executed (Signed)', '9/3/20 15:24'),
            (2632, 'Contract Executed (Signed)', '3/25/21 11:25'),
            (2077, 'Demand Under Process', '10/17/19 18:18'),
            (1810, 'Draft', '5/27/19 14:08'),
            (1810, 'Draft', '8/9/20 16:25'),
            (1810, 'Draft', '8/9/20 17:30'),
            (2632, 'Draft', '11/29/19 10:12'),
            (2632, 'Draft', '11/29/19 10:14'),
            (2632, 'Draft', '11/29/19 10:22'),
            (2632, 'Draft', '11/29/19 10:23'),
            (2632, 'Draft', '1/16/20 17:33'),
            (2077, 'LOI / LOA Issued', '4/30/20 15:01'),
            (2077, 'LOI / LOA Issued', '4/30/20 15:01'),
            (2077, 'LOI / LOA Issued', '5/7/20 14:13'),
            (2077, 'LOI / LOA Issued', '5/7/20 14:13'),
            (2632, 'LOI / LOA Issued', '1/25/21 13:54'),
            (2632, 'On Hold', '6/15/20 13:29'),
            (2632, 'On Hold', '6/18/20 16:18'),
            (2632, 'On Hold', '7/2/20 16:24'),
            (2632, 'On Hold', '7/9/20 13:29'),
            (2632, 'On Hold', '7/16/20 13:55'),
            (1810, 'Pending Director approval', '8/9/20 17:51'),
            (2632, 'Pending Director approval', '1/16/20 18:01'),
            (1810, 'Pending DM Review', '6/23/19 9:53'),
            (1810, 'Pending DM Review', '8/13/20 11:27'),
            (2077, 'Pending DM Review', '7/25/19 8:48'),
            (2632, 'Pending DM Review', '1/22/20 10:13'),
            (1810, 'Pending Manager Approval', '5/27/19 14:08'),
            (1810, 'Pending Manager Approval', '8/9/20 16:49'),
            (1810, 'Pending Manager Approval', '8/9/20 17:32'),
            (2077, 'Pending Manager Approval', '7/20/19 12:45'),
            (2632, 'Pending Manager Approval', '11/29/19 10:25'),
            (2632, 'Pending Manager Approval', '1/16/20 17:35'),
            (2077, 'Pending PR Creation / Update', '7/25/19 8:49'),
            (2632, 'Pending PR Creation / Update', '1/27/20 10:52'),
            (2632, 'Pending PR Creation / Update', '7/27/20 10:24'),
            (2632, 'Pending Service Owner approval', '1/20/20 14:33'),
            (2632, 'Pending Service Owner approval', '1/20/20 14:34'),
            (1810, 'Pending User Input', '6/23/19 11:18'),
            (1810, 'Pending User Input', '8/6/19 15:28'),
            (1810, 'Pending User Input', '8/28/19 15:21'),
            (2632, 'Pending User Input', '1/26/20 10:51'),
            (2077, 'PO Issued', '12/3/20 13:39'),
            (2632, 'PO Issued', '4/6/21 9:54'),
            (2632, 'PR Pending Budget Approval (Finance Division)', '1/29/20 10:31'),
            (2632, 'PR Pending Budget Approval (Finance Division)', '1/29/20 10:31'),
            (2077, 'PR Pending Other Approvals', '7/25/19 16:39'),
            (2632, 'Rejected by Manager', '1/14/20 11:13'),
            (2077, 'SAP Contract Issued (Proc.)', '11/19/20 16:45'),
            (2632, 'SAP Contract Issued (Proc.)', '3/31/21 11:35'),
            (1810, 'Tender Issued', '5/4/21 12:57'),
            (1810, 'Tender Issued', '5/6/21 11:46'),
            (1810, 'Tender Issued', '5/6/21 11:47'),
            (1810, 'Tender Issued', '5/20/21 16:22'),
            (1810, 'Tender Issued', '5/27/21 12:37'),
            (2077, 'Tender Issued', '8/31/19 9:02'),
            (2077, 'Tender Issued', '9/24/19 14:48'),
            (2077, 'Tender Issued', '10/17/19 18:19'),
            (2077, 'Tender Issued', '10/19/19 0:52'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/8/20 9:50'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/8/20 9:52'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/16/20 13:10'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/16/20 13:10'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/19/20 16:36'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '3/19/20 16:36'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '9/23/20 8:58'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '9/24/20 14:07'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/1/20 11:55'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/8/20 13:53'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/15/20 9:43'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/19/20 15:20'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/22/20 12:07'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '10/29/20 13:12'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/2/20 14:01'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/5/20 15:18'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/12/20 14:06'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/17/20 9:51'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/19/20 9:59'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '11/26/20 14:49'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '12/3/20 15:35'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '12/10/20 14:30'),
            (2632, 'Tender Issued', '12/16/20 12:33'),
            (1810, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '7/8/21 12:14'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '1/2/20 12:16'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '1/2/20 12:17'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '1/30/20 15:39'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '1/30/20 15:40'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/6/20 15:23'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/6/20 15:24'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/13/20 13:29'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/13/20 13:29'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/20/20 15:41'),
            (2077, 'Under Commercial Evaluation & Negotiations', '2/20/20 15:41'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/9/20 15:18'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/9/20 15:19'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/16/20 15:31'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/16/20 15:31'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '2/27/20 14:48'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '2/27/20 14:48'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/2/20 13:18'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/2/20 13:19'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/9/20 13:23'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/9/20 13:23'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/16/20 15:54'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/16/20 15:54'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/23/20 12:35'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '4/23/20 12:35'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/14/21 16:00'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Awarding', '1/21/21 14:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '1/23/20 8:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '1/23/20 8:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/5/20 13:11'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/5/20 13:11'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/12/20 11:20'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/12/20 11:20'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/19/20 12:04'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/19/20 12:04'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/26/20 14:54'),
            (2077, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '3/26/20 14:54'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '12/21/20 14:25'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '12/24/20 16:32'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '12/31/20 13:10'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Commercials', '1/7/21 14:04'),
            (1810, 'Under Committee Approvals - Tendering', '3/25/21 17:30'),
            (1810, 'Under Committee Approvals - Tendering', '4/1/21 10:33'),
            (1810, 'Under Committee Approvals - Tendering', '4/9/21 0:20'),
            (1810, 'Under Committee Approvals - Tendering', '4/17/21 18:12'),
            (2632, 'Under Committee Approvals - Tendering', '9/17/20 15:44'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '5/14/20 12:17'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '5/21/20 13:59'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '5/21/20 14:00'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '5/30/20 3:43'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '5/30/20 3:43'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/4/20 16:27'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/4/20 16:28'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/11/20 13:15'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/11/20 13:15'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/18/20 12:20'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '6/25/20 13:22'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '7/2/20 14:13'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '7/9/20 13:43'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '7/16/20 14:58'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '1/28/21 15:02'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '2/4/21 13:38'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '2/10/21 13:26'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '2/11/21 15:44'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '2/18/21 15:17'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '2/25/21 11:35'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '3/1/21 15:23'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '3/4/21 11:57'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Drafting & Finalization (Proc., Legal, TNO, Finance, DPO, Vendor)', '3/11/21 13:38'),
            (1810, 'Under Contract Management Review (TNO)', '8/16/20 14:50'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Management Review (TNO)', '1/22/20 11:02'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Management Review (TNO)', '1/26/20 10:13'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '7/23/20 12:39'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '7/29/20 17:00'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '8/6/20 12:53'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '8/13/20 15:12'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '8/20/20 15:35'),
            (2077, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '8/27/20 16:36'),
            (2632, 'Under Contract Signatures (Legal, Proc., Vendor)', '3/18/21 14:29'),
            (1810, 'Under Financial Review', '6/12/19 12:20'),
            (2077, 'Under Financial Review', '7/20/19 13:03'),
            (2632, 'Under Financial Review', '1/21/20 11:27'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '9/26/19 11:01'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '10/17/19 16:24'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '10/24/19 16:50'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/5/19 14:59'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/12/19 17:00'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/26/19 17:07'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/2/20 16:40'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/9/20 17:16'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/16/20 16:51'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/30/20 14:29'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/6/20 17:17'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/13/20 16:24'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/20/20 12:48'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/27/20 14:55'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/5/20 16:15'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/15/20 17:17'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/19/20 16:17'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/27/20 16:04'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/9/20 13:16'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/16/20 17:24'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/17/20 1:49'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/2/20 19:19'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/9/20 17:16'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/16/20 17:27'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/24/20 1:14'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/29/20 16:14'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '8/9/20 16:23'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '8/20/20 22:47'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '8/27/20 16:09'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '9/3/20 17:15'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '9/10/20 16:24'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '10/1/20 17:00'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '11/12/20 11:11'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/3/20 17:12'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/3/20 17:13'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/24/20 10:57'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '12/31/20 16:33'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/7/21 18:07'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/14/21 16:55'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/18/21 12:14'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/21/21 12:17'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '1/28/21 16:32'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/7/21 12:15'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/13/21 13:43'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/18/21 18:44'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '2/25/21 18:20'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/7/21 10:16'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/17/21 10:52'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '3/18/21 18:11'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/17/21 18:13'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/22/21 16:41'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '4/29/21 15:40'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Input (User, Legal, Proc., Finance, DPO)', '7/23/20 15:52'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/23/20 16:06'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/30/20 14:51'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/7/20 17:45'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/7/20 17:45'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/14/20 17:15'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/14/20 17:16'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/21/20 15:44'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/21/20 15:44'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/1/20 14:56'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/1/20 14:56'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/4/20 14:43'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/4/20 14:43'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/11/20 12:02'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/11/20 12:02'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/18/20 12:48'),
            (1810, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/25/20 11:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '7/30/19 18:51'),
            (2077, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/7/19 12:21'),
            (2077, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/22/19 10:05'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/9/20 8:56'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/9/20 8:56'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/9/20 11:07'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/13/20 17:20'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/13/20 17:20'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/20/20 15:24'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/20/20 15:24'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/27/20 16:07'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '2/27/20 16:07'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '3/5/20 16:30'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '3/5/20 16:30'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '3/27/20 15:15'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '3/27/20 15:15'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/3/20 14:50'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/3/20 14:50'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/9/20 17:21'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/9/20 17:21'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/16/20 16:44'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/16/20 16:44'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/23/20 15:10'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/23/20 15:10'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/30/20 14:36'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '4/30/20 14:37'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/7/20 17:00'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/7/20 17:00'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/14/20 16:27'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/14/20 16:27'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/21/20 15:05'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/21/20 15:05'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/30/20 16:02'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '5/30/20 16:02'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/1/20 14:53'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/1/20 14:53'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/4/20 16:01'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/4/20 16:01'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/11/20 12:53'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '6/11/20 12:53'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '7/29/20 17:17'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/10/20 9:31'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/13/20 16:06'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/20/20 15:32'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '8/27/20 14:31'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '9/3/20 15:26'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '9/6/20 15:33'),
            (2632, 'Under Pre-Tender Proc. Review (Proc.)', '9/10/20 10:59'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '9/10/20 10:41'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '9/17/20 13:29'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '9/24/20 13:04'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '10/1/20 15:56'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '10/8/20 15:24'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '10/15/20 15:06'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '10/22/20 16:05'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '10/29/20 15:24'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '11/5/20 15:22'),
            (2077, 'Under SAP Contract Creation / Release (Proc.)', '11/12/20 16:29'),
            (1810, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '6/3/21 17:07'),
            (1810, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '6/10/21 11:22'),
            (1810, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '6/20/21 0:32'),
            (1810, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '6/24/21 16:02'),
            (1810, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '7/1/21 13:05'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '10/20/19 9:38'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '10/24/19 15:15'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '10/31/19 15:32'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '10/31/19 15:32'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/7/19 17:42'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/7/19 17:42'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/16/19 0:45'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/16/19 0:45'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/16/19 0:53'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/16/19 0:53'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/21/19 15:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/21/19 15:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '11/28/19 14:58'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/5/19 15:13'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/5/19 15:13'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/11/19 8:35'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/11/19 8:36'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/23/19 15:02'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/23/19 15:02'),
            (2077, 'Under Technical Evaluation (TE)', '12/26/19 15:28')
    ) AS myData (id, subStatus, createdDate)
    ),
    CleanSampleData AS ( /* Clean up dates */
        SELECT
            id          = sd.id,
            subStatus   = sd.subStatus,
            createdDate = CAST(sd.createdDate AS datetime)
        FROM    SampleData AS sd
    ),
    CollapseSubStatus   AS ( /* collapse consecutive records where status doesn't actually change */
        SELECT
            csd.id,
            csd.subStatus,
            csd.createdDate,
            statusChanged   = CASE
                                WHEN csd.subStatus = LAG(csd.subStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY csd.id ORDER BY csd.createdDate) THEN
                                    0
                                ELSE
                                    1
                            END
        FROM    CleanSampleData AS csd
    )
SELECT /* use OVER PATITION BY to calculate the difference in seconds until the next status change */
    css.id,
    css.subStatus,
    css.createdDate,
    Seconds = ISNULL(DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                    LAG(css.createdDate) OVER (PARTITION BY css.id ORDER BY css.createdDate),
                    css.createdDate
            ), 0)
FROM    CollapseSubStatus AS css
WHERE   css.statusChanged = 1
```